# How do applications like TextMe or MagicJack get their phone numbers

Tags: android, ios, api, numbers

I want to create an application that provides an American phone number to users but I just don't know how to get the actual phone numbers

For example: Magic Jack is a phone number provider. You pay them monthly and they give you a functional phone number that works with text and phone calls.

I'm currently trying to figure out how companies like MagicJack get the phone numbers.

So far I've searched the internet in hope of finding some answer regarding how they get their phone numbers but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at companies like Twilio and Nexmo, I believe Twilio is the leader IMO - there's an API to purchase phone numbers (toll free and local DIDs) where you can easily buy numbers for a small monthly holding fee and pass it to your customers if you'd like.

Reference @ https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135247-How-to-Search-for-and-Buy-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-from-Console